# How do I get selected row value in C# WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, datagrid

I am writing this in C# WPF using Powershell Commands.

I first create the Datagrid column objects:

```
public class Item
{
    public object ID { get; set; }
    public object ProcessName { get; set; }
    public object Handles { get; set; }
    public object NPM { get; set; }
    public object PM { get; set; }
    public object WS { get; set; }
    public object Path { get; set; }
}
```

Then the following code populates a Datagrid that shows all running processes on my PC:

```
private void btnGetProcess_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Creates fields
    DataGridTextColumn c1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    c1.Header = "ID";
    c1.Binding = new Binding("ID");

    dgdProcessList.Columns.Add(c1);
    DataGridTextColumn c2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    c2.Header = "Process Name";
    c2.Binding = new Binding("ProcessName");
    dgdProcessList.Columns.Add(c2);

    DataGridTextColumn c3 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    c3.Header = "Handles";
    c3.Binding = new Binding("Handles");
    dgdProcessList.Columns.Add(c3);

    DataGridTextColumn c4 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    c4.Header = "NPM(K)";
    c4.Binding = new Binding("NPM");
    dgdProcessList.Columns.Add(c4);

    DataGridTextColumn c5 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    c5.Header = "PM(K)";
    c5.Binding = new Binding("PM");
    dgdProcessList.Columns.Add(c5);

    DataGridTextColumn c6 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    c6.Header = "WS(K)";
    c6.Binding = new Binding("WS");
    dgdProcessList.Columns.Add(c6);

    DataGridTextColumn c7 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    c6.Header = "Path";
    c6.Binding = new Binding("Path");
    dgdProcessList.Columns.Add(c7);

    //Connection to hostname successful
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runspace.Open();

    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(); // Create a new PowerShell instance
    ps.Runspace = runspace; // Add the instance to the runspace
    ps.Commands.AddScript("Get-Process | Select-Object ID, ProcessName, Handles, NPM, PM, WS, Path"); // Add a script
    Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();

    runspace.Close();

    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
    {
        object IDOutput;
        object ProcessNameOutput;
        object HandlesOutput;
        object NPMOutput;
        object PMOutput;
        object WSOutput;
        object PathOutput;

        IDOutput = obj.Properties["ID"].Value;
        ProcessNameOutput = obj.Properties["ProcessName"].Value;
        HandlesOutput = obj.Properties["Handles"].Value;
        NPMOutput = obj.Properties["NPM"].Value;
        PMOutput = obj.Properties["PM"].Value;
        WSOutput = obj.Properties["WS"].Value;
        PathOutput = obj.Properties["Path"].Value;
        dgdProcessList.Items.Add(new Item() { ID = IDOutput, ProcessName = ProcessNameOutput, Handles = HandlesOutput, NPM = NPMOutput, PM = PMOutput, WS = WSOutput, Path = PathOutput });
    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get the selected row value. More particularly, I want to be able to get the "ID" field value of the row I have selected.

I've spent the last few hours playing with different property variations (SelectedItem, SelectedValue, GetValue, etc.), but I can't seem to get it working. For example, this code returns a value (ProjectName.FormName+Item), but not the actual object value:

```
MessageBox.Show(dgdProcessList.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: What is `Item`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that is the literal text I receive when I use the messagebox example above.

Comment: No, I mean in `dgdProcessList.Items.Add(new Item(){...})` <-- what is `Item`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen when I hover Item() in Visual Studio, it displays Item() is Item.Item(). I updated my initial post to display the whole code if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the `SelectedItem` property of the `DataGrid` to your `Item` type:

```
var selectedItem = dgdProcessList.SelectedItem as Item;
if(selectedItem != null)
    MessageBox.Show(selectedItem.ID.ToString());
```